# Giving dynamic names for file creating

Tags: javascript

```
url: '/folder/file' + i + '.js',
```

The above url creates file1.js, file2.js etc etc

I want the url to be : `/foldename +file[i] + i + '.js'`

Can i have an array file which would control the names of the file being created.

Comment: Did you **try it**? If yes, did it work? If no, what seemed to go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uh... Yeah, actually you can:

```
var file = Array();
file[0] = 'file';
file[1] = 'otherfilename';
/* ... */
var url = '/folder/' + file[j] + i + '.js';
```